# Button that opens a new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm writing a program where I am supposed to have a title screen for a game, where you can click a 'play' button that opens a different window and simultaneously closes the other one. What I am attempting to do is utilize an ActionListener for a button that makes the current window invisible while simultaneously making a different window visible. I am having a hard time getting this to work and am encountering a lot of syntax and logical errors. I'm quite certain there is a better way to do this, so any pointers will be greatly appreciated. I am using swing. *Disclaimer: beginner java level programmer lol :p*

My first class includes this (does not include my imports):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creating the Frame
        MyFrame menuFrame = new MyFrame();

    // (here i have code for the frame in my actual program)
    }
    static class MyFrame extends JFrame {

        MyFrame () {

            this.setDefaultCloseOperation
                    (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            this.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("logo.png")));
            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);

            new EightOff.returnHomeListener (this);

        }
    }
}
```

My other class that has the other frame being opened includes the following button and action listener where I am trying to reference my frame from **GameMenu**:

```
public class EightOff
{
private static JButton returnHome = new JButton("Return to Game Menu");

public static class returnHomeListener implements ActionListener {
        public returnHomeListener(GameMenu.MyFrame myFrame) {

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                returnHomeListener (JFrame visibleFrame) {
                visibleFrame.toSetVisible (true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Swing has a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) layout manager that allows you to use one JFrame, but switch the underlying JPanel from a title JPanel to a game JPanel.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will teach you the correct way to create a Swing GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by having a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

The `ActionListener` should be registered to the button, so if can be notified when some action occurs, for example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
                button.addActionListener(new TestActionListener());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(button);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'd prfefer if you did't do that");            
        }

    }
}
```

In order to make changes to a object, you first need a reference to that object.  This is pretty basic, Java 101 kind of stuff and you should have a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details.

You should also have a read of the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) for `JFrame` to get a better understanding of what properties and functionality the class provides.

Having a look at [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) also wouldn't hurt.

I'd recommend having a look at [How to use `CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of trying to hide/show windows, you'll have a better user experience generally.